# How can I get this value using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Not sure what that's called but it represents the user that created the forum thread:

```
...
    <a href="http://myforum.com/forum/most-fav-action-movies/" id="thread_title_10178" style="font-weight:bold">Most Favorite Action Movies</a>     
  </div>
  <div class="smallfont">
    <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('http://myforum.com/forum/members/u506/', '_self')">JOANVENGE</span>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="alt2" title="Replies: 17, Views: 651">
  <div class="smallfont" style="text-align:right; white-space:nowrap">
...
```

So in this case it's the "JOANVENGE" string I am trying to get. Currently I am getting the `a` links using this:

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.
                                      Descendants ( "a" ).
                                      Where ( link => link.Id.StartsWith ( linkIdPrefix ) );
```

But that doesn't contain anything more than the forum url and id. That's why I am not sure how to get that text beyond the `a` link.

EDIT: I am currently creating another `IEnumerable` that only collects "span" and then matches them to the first list, but this seems cumbersome and fragile, because for some reason `span` links are 1 more than `a` links so I am doing `index + 1`. Now it works fine but it would be more robust if I could access this information from the links of the first list directly. Next and Previous nodes until I hit `null` values also do not reach to `span` section. So I assume whatever the case may be, these are separate entities for HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). For example the following code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.htm");

// get any SPAN element recursively with a STYLE attribute set to 'cursor:pointer'
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@style='cursor:pointer']").InnerHtml);
```

will dump

```
JOANVENGE
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is still the issue of matching them by hand, using indices.

Comment: You can change @style='something' by @id='other something' in the XPATH expression, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, I meant I am already getting `a` link but now with your code, only retrieves the other part but since they are done separately, they have to be matched by index. Because there are now 2 collections. I was hoping to get them together, so accessing `JOANVENGE` via some property or method on the `a` link.